# Usage of both scalar and array in smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

How can I use both scalar and array in smart pointer?

The old way of using new and delete pointer:

```
int *p;

if (useScalar) {
    p = new int;
} else {
    p = new int[10];
}

if (useScalar) {
    delete p;
} else {
    delete[] p;
}
```

In smart pointer, I have to use 2 pointers for each scalar and array pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int);
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p2(new int[10]);
```

How can I decrease to use only 1 smart pointer?

Comment: You can write your own smart pointer which stores a `bool useScalar` for determining whether to use `delete` or `delete[]`.

Comment: Could you allocate `p = new int[1]` and pretend that it is a pointer to scalar?

Comment: You could use `int[1]` as scalar, maybe it simplifies other areas of your program too...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: good question. But should I write `delete[] p;` If I allocate like `int* p=new int[1]` ? I know that every use of **new** should be matched with **delete** ? Which is one correct here to use?

Comment: @Destructor You write `delete[] p` for an array of any size, including arrays of size 1. That's the idea behind this trick - to let you use the same destructor in both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a custom deleter, you can use the same type for either pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> p = {nullptr, [](int*){}};
if (useScalar) {
    p = {
        new int,
        [](int* p){delete p;}
    };
} else {
    p = {
        new int[10],
        [](int* p){delete[] p;},
    };
}
```